# What are good alternatives to measure clusters in large square grids?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, netlogo

I have a time problem getting the list of sizes (number of patches) of clusters in a patch environment (colored regions) in a NetLogo model. For small grid values (world size in NetLogo) as 50 x 50, 100 x 100 or even 150 x 150 standard DFS of BFS becomes efficient but as order increases these procedures becomes infeasible. My task is to compute same results but for grids with at least 10000 x 10000 patches or higher.

I tried Union-Find with Hoshen-Kopelman algorithm but my actual NetLogo implementation spends about 5 hrs for a patche grid of order 500 x 500.

Does any one knows any algorithm to compute or labeling clusters for worlds of at least 1000 x 1000 patches?

Could I get some improvement, If instead of use patches and Netlogo, I switch to C/C++ or other programming language?

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Great Day

Comment: Can we see your NetLogo code? I don't think you need any algorithm, you should be able to do this with NetLogo primitives but I am unclear what you mean by a cluster in this question.

Comment: Thanks @JenB for your comment, yes I supposed that,  my last attempt was to create a model from model in [link](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/2328#model_tabs_browse_info) (which is exactly what i need for two colours and large patche worlds), it basically uses recursion and breadth search in its 4-neighbours. Unafortunately I still have complications with huge worlds (at least 1000000 patches) since the model needs to detect large clusters then the recursion procedure notifies "recursion too deep", thanks for your information. Regards

Answer (score 0):

My code is basically this model [Clusters with Recursion](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/2328#model_tabs_browse_info).

The model finds the clusters very well when clusters has a moderate size, but if your setup procedure generates large clusters then recursion says "recursion too deep" and don not report results, now my initial question could be rephrased, how to avoid this "recursio too deep" with netlogo ?

Netlogo code:

```
globals [npixel caux final-participante1 final-participante2 r i j intera2 clist1 clist2 nc1 nc2]
patches-own
[
  partido influencia votoduro
  cluster  
]

to find-clusters
  loop [ 
    let seed one-of patches with [cluster = nobody] 
    if seed = nobody
    [ contarclusvar
      stop ]
    ask seed 
    [ set cluster self 
      grow-cluster ] 
  ] 
  display 
end

to setup1
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
ask patches [set partido 0 set influencia 0 set cluster nobody]
set npixel[]
set final-participante1 0
set final-participante2 0

set r  (L + 1)   
set-patch-size ps
resize-world 0 L 0 L

set participante2 (L + 1) * (L + 1) - participante1

set i 0
set j 0

   repeat r
  [
    repeat r
    [
    set npixel sentence npixel patch i j

    set j j + 1
    ]
    set i i + 1
    set j 0
   ]
set Caux npixel

let N r * r

repeat participante1
 [
   let z random N
   ask item z npixel [set pcolor white set partido 1 set influencia 1 set votoduro 1]
   set npixel replace-item z npixel item (N - 1 ) npixel
   set N N - 1
 ]

 repeat participante2
 [
   let z random N
   ask item z npixel [set pcolor gray set partido 2 set influencia 1 set votoduro 1]
   set npixel replace-item z npixel item (N - 1 ) npixel
   set N N - 1
 ]

;------------------- Procedure
set clist1 []
set clist2 []

let ciclos 0
let intera 0
let aux 0
let nulo 0

if participante1 + participante2 > r * r
   [stop]
let C1 participante1
let C2 participante2

repeat 75
[
  set i 0
  set j 0
  set npixel Caux

   set N r * r
   set intera 0
   set aux 0
   let aux2 (((ciclos - 1) * r * r) + intera2)              

  repeat (r * r)
 [
   let z random N 
   ask item z npixel 
   [
        let sum-inf1 sum ([influencia] of neighbors4 with [partido = 1])
        let sum-inf2 sum ([influencia] of neighbors4 with [partido = 2])


   if (sum-inf2 = sum-inf1) and (partido = 1) [ask item z npixel [set pcolor black set partido 0 set influencia 0 ] set Nulo Nulo + 1 set C1 C1 - 1 set aux aux + 1 set intera2 intera] 
   if (sum-inf2 = sum-inf1) and (partido = 2) [ask item z npixel [set pcolor black set partido 0 set influencia 0 ] set Nulo Nulo + 1 set C2 C2 - 1 set aux aux + 1 set intera2 intera]

  if ((sum-inf1 > sum-inf2) and ((partido = 2) or (partido = 0))) [
         set pcolor white set partido 1 set influencia 1
         set C1 C1 + 1 set C2 C2 - 1 set aux aux + 1 set intera2 intera
       ]

 if ((sum-inf2 > sum-inf1) and ((partido = 1) or (partido = 0))) [
       set pcolor gray set partido 2 set influencia 1
       set C2 C2 + 1 set C1 C1 - 1 set aux aux + 1 set intera2 intera
     ]

   set npixel replace-item z npixel item (N - 1 ) npixel
   set N N - 1
   set intera intera + 1
   ] 

  if (intera - aux) > (r * r) - 1  [
  stop
  ]
 ] 
] 
end

to contarclusvar
let comp []

      set comp ([cluster] of patches with [pcolor = white]) 
      set comp remove-duplicates comp 
      set nc1 length comp 

  foreach comp [ set clist1 sentence clist1 count patches with [cluster = ? and pcolor = white]
        ]
   set comp []

      set comp ([cluster] of patches with [pcolor = gray]) 
      set comp remove-duplicates comp 
      set nc2 length comp 

 foreach comp [ set clist2 sentence clist2 count patches with [cluster = ? and pcolor = gray]
      ]
end

to grow-cluster  
  ask neighbors4 with [(cluster = nobody) and (pcolor = [pcolor] of myself)]
  [ set cluster [cluster] of myself
    grow-cluster ] 
end

to show-clusters
  let counter 0
  loop [ 
    let p one-of patches with [plabel = ""] 
    if p = nobody
      [ stop ] 
    ask p
    [ ask patches with [cluster = [cluster] of myself]
      [ set plabel counter ] ]
    set counter counter + 1
  ] 
end
```